# Backticks not working when encapsulating path in quotes

Tags: bash, files, timestamps

I have a script where I want to clean out old files when there are more than a set limit.

I have this command:

```
/bin/rm -f `/bin/ls -t $bkup_p/mysql.daily/*  2> /dev/null | /bin/awk 'NR>'5`
```

which works and because there could be a space in $bkup_p, I tried to change it to

```
/bin/rm -f `/bin/ls -t "$bkup_p/mysql.daily/*"  2> /dev/null | /bin/awk 'NR>'5`
```

But that doesn't work. It doesn't show the files in question, it's just empty

Comment: Which is why you should use the saner construct `$(...)` instead of backticks.

Comment: is **awk 'NR>'5** a copy/paste typo (though It should'nt be part of problem) ? can you update with exact status of "doesn't work" ? (too many files deleted ? files not found ? syntax error ?)

Comment: Doesn't work in the sense that it doesn't list the files that needs to be deleted, it's just empty. I tried constructing with the $(...), but I couldn't make it work, can you give me a way?

Comment: @sati-katsura Ok, got the expression working with $() instead of backticks, but it still does not list any files if the path contains spaces.

Comment: Your `... /bin/awk 'NR>'5` looks wrong. The awk "script" here is only 'NR>' The 5 is outside the script where a filename would be.

Comment: @DocSalvager: no. Only characters that are special to shell need to be quoted; consecutive characters that are quoted inclusive-or nonspecial make up one argument. `NR'>'5` would also work, as would `NR\>5`. Though `'NR>5'` or `"NR>5"` is more convenient for human readers.

Comment: And of course `'NR > 5'` is harder to get wrong than `'NR > '5` if you want to write with whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you shouldn't use `ls` for that. But if your environment doesn't have anything more sensible and you [**know the caveats**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), you **might** get away with it, if your file names are *nice enough*: no whitespace or unprintable characters, and especially nothing that the shell interprets as a globbing character (at least `?*[]`).

Using something like Perl to sort the files, or putting the dates in the file names so you can depend on the glob order would be better.

---

With that said: in your second snippet, the asterisk is quoted, so globbing doesn't happen. You'd see an error about `some dir/mysql.daily/*` not existing, but you don't since you redirected the error output away.

File names with spaces will give you the problem that the output from the command substitution is split along the spaces, so something like `some dir/foo` will be given to `rm` in two parts: `some` and `dir/foo`. Hopefully neither of them exist, since they'd get removed.

If only your directory name contains spaces, you could just `cd` into it first. Or, set `IFS` to only contain a newline (instead of the default space, tab, newline). You mentioned a NAS, so chances are you have busybox. This should work in both busybox and bash, and print the file names, one per line:

```
IFS=$'\n'
printf "%s\n" $( ls -t "$bkup_p/mysql.daily/"* | tail -n +6 )
```

Replace `printf "%s\n"` with `rm` to remove the files, if you're sure it works correctly.

Comment: This is perfect, well it is limited (busybox), and with this I could get it working, thankyou. I modified it a bit:

Comment: Darned, forgot I couldn't press Enter :-) I changed the +6 to $(expr $day_ret + 1), apparently the variable is cast a string. This way I can still write to the log that I keep 5 files, and then have the script use the number 6.

Comment: @KennethFribert, oh, right, of course `awk "NR > $number"` should work too if you have a working `awk`. Note that with `tail`, the leading `+` is _important_, compare `seq 10 | tail -n +3` to `seq 10 | tail -n 3`. Anyway, better use `$(( ))` instead of `expr`: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression

Answer (score 2):

Bash is not very handy when it comes to filtering files on modification time and executing command on them.

I would recommend to try z-shell instead, so first run `zsh`, and then

```
rm -i -- "$bkup_p"/mysql.daily/*(DN.Om[1,5])
```

This removes the oldest five plain files in the given directory, what I suspect is probably what you are trying to achieve. Obviously at the end of the day change `rm -i` to `rm -f` if needed.

To remove five newest files do

```
rm -i -- "$bkup_p"/mysql.daily/*(DN.om[1,5])
```

---

Now, how it works. Everything inside `()` are so called glob qualifiers, which basically filter files depending on your needs:

- `D` include dotfiles (those which start with `.`)
- `N` do not report error if no matches
- `.` selects only plain files
- `om` sorts on modification time (`Om` sorts in reverse order)
- `[1,5]` selects only five files from the list

I believe all of that should work even with special characters in filenames (spaces, newlines, etc.)

Comment: I'd say it's better to omit the `N` here as otherwise you would pass no argument to `rm` which would confuse it (and without `-f`, would report an error (a less useful one) anyway).

Comment: I need to keep it in bash, this is a NAS, and has a very limited linux, and the script is used on quite a few around the world, and I can't expect the users to install z-shell :-(

Comment: @KennethFribert You wrote that there cold be space in `$bkup_p` directory, but are there spaces inside filenames as well? If not probably `/bin/rm -f $(/bin/ls -t "$bkup_p"/mysql.daily/* 2> /dev/null | /bin/awk 'NR>5')` should work.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against parsing the output of `ls` as it doesn't properly format output for piping into a new command and it has portability problems.
I would try something like this instead

```
find $bkup_p/mysql.daily/ -type f -a -mtime +7 -a -name "*.sql" -a -exec rm -f {} +
```

note:

- `"*.sql"` change this as necessary
- `-mtime +7` means *if this file was modified more (+) than 7 days ago, obviously change this as needed too

In the case you want to make sure you always have the 10 newest files - no matter what, (and you have GNU `find`) you could try

```
find $bkup_p/mysql.daily/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -a -printf "%T+\t%p\n" | sort -r | sed -n '10,$p' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs rm -f
```

for more info on formatting `find` output with the `-printf` operator, see

```
man find | less '+/^\s*-printf'
```

Comment: Yes, I tried with the find command, but I need to save a number of files, not files younger than a date. This is a backup script, and if the backup fails for some reason, I don't want the older files to disappear because of age, but rather keep the old ones. Also the dialect of linux here is a bit limited in regards to the find command :-(

Comment: oh ok, what linux is it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem of the `*` not working is because when you quote it, it doesn't expand.

Compare the results of this: `echo *` with this: `echo "*"`.

---

The robust solution is to use an array, one file on each array position.

If you are lucky enough and your find support this `-printf`:

```
dir="$bkup_p/mysql.daily/"

find "$dir" -printf '%T@:%i\n'
```

All filenames will be avoided. Each file will be a line. And a line of only numbers, an optional dot and a colon.

That could be easily sorted:

```
find "$dir" -printf '%T@:%i\n' | sort -rn
```

The simplest array is the positional arguments.
This will set all files in the directory to the list of positional arguments:

```
set -f; set -- $(find "$dir" -printf '%T@:%i\n' | sort -n )
```

The set -f will avoid expansion of any filename that is also a wilcard `*`.
To avoid (remove) the first 6 file names, just `shift` them:

```
shift 5
```

And do what you need to the remaining files:

```
for    f
do     rm -f "$(find "$dir" -inum "${f#*:}")"
done
```

## The whole script.

The whole script (Robust for any file name) becomes:

```
dir="$bkup_p/mysql.daily/"

set -f
set -- $(find "$dir" -type f -printf '%T@:%i\n'|sort -rn)
shift 5

for    f
do     rm -f "$(find "$dir" -inum "${f#*:}")"
done
```